# any way to limit result by node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query:

```
MATCH (user:Users)-[buy:Sales]->(item:Items)<-[buy2:Sales]- (user2:Users)-[buy_other:Sales]->(item2:Items)
where item.category = item2.category
return
user.mail, item2.id
```

the idea is to get items that the first user could be interested in that other user2 also bought, but i want to limit the results to max 2 item2 id per user

I know i can limit results in general, with limit 10 for example, but that means that those 10 results could all be for the same user.

Any help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by inserting a COLLECTing and getting the first n items of it.

```
MATCH (user:Users)-[buy:Sales]->(item:Items)<-[buy2:Sales]- (user2:Users)-[buy_other:Sales]->(item2:Items)
WHERE item.category = item2.category

// this is where you collect and get some items of it
WITH user,COLLECT(item2)[0..2] AS item2s
UNWIND item2s AS item2


RETURN
user.mail, item2.id
```

Comment: If i want the first 2 items being only the ones with most ocurrences? 
I was trying before

    RETURN
    user.mail, item2, count(item2) as ocurrence
    ORDER BY ocurrence DESC

Comment: before COLLECTing , you have to ORDER them. The COLLECT() will create a list of items in that order.